# How do you run an extension-less file that you know is a Mach-O 64-bit executable on macOS?

Tags: macos

Bit of a weird question, but I have a particular file that is without an extension. On checking with the "file" command, it seems to be a "Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64" type of file. Since it is extensionless, how do I run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Most* executables (programs) are extension-less; the "Execute" permission bit is used to indicate that it's allowed to run the file as a program, and the kernel will recognize its type by content rather than filename. (The primary purpose of file extensions to look up an associated program becomes irrelevant if it's already known that the file itself is the program.)

Use `chmod +x` on the file in Terminal, and it will become possible to run the program by specifying its path as the command. (Usually a relative path such as `./myfile` is enough, the `./` meaning "current directory", but an absolute path such as `~/Downloads/myfile` also works.)

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ chmod a+x myfile
$ ./myfile
```

From what I've heard about macOS, it might also be necessary to remove the "Quarantine" attribute if the file is downloaded – it's a separate topic.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the quarantine part?

Comment: I don't actually know anything about the quarantine part, except what I've read in other posts. Search for `"com.apple.quarantine"` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the file using `./` in your terminal.

So for example

```
./filename
```

It could also be that the file is currently not marked as executable. To fix this, you can use chmod like so;

```
chmod +x filename
```

Comment: this worked! thanks.